# How to add arrow to my generated heatmap in R?

Tags: r, heatmap

I know how to create a heatmap but I want to add an arrow next to my gene of interest on the specific row. I saw some heatmaps that have the arrows but I couldn't find the solution.
here is my code for the heatmap with heatmap.3 :

```
heatmap.3(as.matrix(exprs(df)),keysize = 1, Colv=T,Rowv=F,main = "My heatmap", 
 ColSideColors=Col.matrix,side.height.fraction=0.5,col=my.colors, 
  dendrogram="column", scale="none",  breaks=my.breaks, key=TRUE)
```

Here is an example of how to draw a heatmap with heatmap.3 package.

```
  ## load library
  require("GMD")
  require(cluster)
  ## load data
  data(ruspini)
  ## heatmap on a `dist' object
  x <- gdist(ruspini)
  main <- "Heatmap of Ruspini data"
  dev.new(width=10,height=10)
  heatmap.3(x, main=main) # with a title and a map in square!
```

and here is the link to another heatmap to visualise what I am looking for: (adding an arrow next to the heatmap) if you look at the heatmap you could find two arrows next to the y-axis of the heatmap.
It's from this article:
Veillonella, Firmicutes: Microbes disguised as Gram negatives , doi:10.4056/sigs.2981345

http://standardsingenomics.org/index.php/sigen/article/viewFile/298/1064/9070

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should provide a working example (e.g. with a matrix containing random data), and include the relevant `library` call so that we know where `heatmap.3` comes from.

Comment: I've edited my post and add an example after my code. my main point is not how to draw a heatmap but how to add an arrow next to a specific gene ( entry ) in the heatmap which I found in several publication. I also add the link to one of the publications that I have seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a variation of this answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427956/2615477. Try arrows() with xpd=T:

```
arrows(x0, y0, x1, y1, xpd=T)
```